# Documents are being displayed with a title equivalent to first words in document in search results. How can I change this to use the file name?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

My search results in my enterprise search aren't displaying the file name or title property.  Instead, they're showing the first words of the actual document content as the title.  For example, we have a policy titled "Cash Counting for Associates".  If I search "cash counting", it's coming back just fine.  However, the title displayed in the results is "Policies and Procedures", which are the first words in the actual document.

Why is it doing this? How can I change this so that it will try to use the title property, and if that's blank, use the file name as the title in the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a well identified issue which was fixed with the Oct 2013 CU update to SP 2013.

This happens because the managed property ‘Title’ is mapped to crawled property ‘MetadataExtractorTitle’ by default as first priority and there was no way to change the order of this crawled property unless October 2013 Cumulative Update was applied.

However, this issue has been addressed in October 2013 Cumulative Update. So, in order to fix this issue without a display template workaround, download and install October 2013 Cumulative Update for SharePoint 2013 on all Web Front End Servers, reboot the machines and run the Products Configuration Wizard on all servers.

Once the upgrade is complete, go to Central Administration > Search Service Application > Search Schema and search for managed property ‘Title.’ Now, inside the mappings of the managed property, you should be able to see the following:

'MetadataExtractorTitle' -- crawled property becomes visible after applying October 2013 CU

Move the mapped crawled property ‘MetadataExtractorTitle’ down to the last position and save the managed property. Then reset the index (optional), perform a full crawl against the content sources and refresh any cache associated with Site Collection. Once the full crawl is complete, you should see the correct titles for documents in search results,

Link to furthern reading here: http://consultant.tamjid.com/425/fixed-search-results-not-showing-document-titles/

Comment: Ransher, what is the display template workaround? I am willing to go that path.  Thanks

Comment: @RansherSIngh Thanks for your answer, you saved my day.

Comment: @User5590 Glad to have helped :)

Comment: @RansherSingh Any idea how to fix this in O365 SharePoint online

Comment: @Digant we were talking about older 2013 on-prem above, it should not even be an issue with Online. Are you not seeing 'MetadataExtractorTitle' property online?

Comment: Thanks Ransher, I managed  to moved "metadatarxtractortitle" to top in search scope and all good now.

Comment: Hi Ransher, i am working with SharePoint online and I have the same issue. I made the change as you mentioned but it does not seem to work for me. Here is how my mapped crawled properties for Title look like: ows_LinkFilename, Title, MetadataExtractorTitle. Any thoughts? I referred to this link as well: https://hangconsult.com/2016/05/19/sharepoint-101-o365-search-results-filename/