# SharePoint Search not displaying file name in results

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, enterprise-search

In the search results of our SharePoint 2013 Search, the results aren't displaying the name of the file.  Instead, it seems to be using the `Title` metadata property.  I've tried following the steps as outlined [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131773/documents-are-being-displayed-with-a-title-equivalent-to-first-words-in-document).  I've moved the `MetadataExtractorTitle` crawled property to the bottom (as you can see below).  However, my results are still showing the `Title` rather than the file name.

How can I change this?

[image: SP Search]

Comment: The file name property is: Basic:displaytitle. try adding it and moving it to the top of your list. Note that I think this is only for office docs. Basic:10 covers all docs if I remember correctly. You may want to add both.

Comment: `Basic:displaytitle` and `Basic:10` are the first two in my list.

Comment: Did you do a full crawl after changing the properties?

Answer (score 1):

What is the build version of your SharePoint installation? Run PowerShell command **`(Get-SpFarm).BuildVersion`** to know your SPFarm version

If your Farm is not up to date I recommend your to first install all missing CUs and Servcice packs. The latest build version is 15.0.4719.1002

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Currently running 15.0.4719.1000

Answer (score 0):

Do an Index Reset followed by a full crawl - if that is an option for you.